# Change streams detect origin

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I use MongoDB change streams in my application:

```js
let changeStream = collection.watch();

changeStream.on("error", (err) => {
    if (err.code === 40573) {

        // change stream is not supported
        // ignore everything
        console.log("Database/cluster is not running as replica set, could not watch for changes: ", err);

    } else {

        console.log("Error in watch streams", err);

    }
});

changeStream.on("change", (event) => {

    // how to detect from where are the changes initialized?
    console.log("DB CHANGE EVENT", event);

});
```

Is there a way to "detect" from where are the changes made?
For example, my application has called `collection.insertOne(...)` or i have a document modified via MongoDB Compass.

A name, a PID or anything?
I need to figure out if the changes are made from my application, or from "external"

EDIT: Example event.

```js
{
  _id: {
    _data: '82638277230000000E2B022C0100296E5A100430F39BD1192F4B448E06283E86CC38F246645F69640064637A444B8F0DAFBFA0F2B0580004'
  },
  operationType: 'update',
  clusterTime: new Timestamp({ t: 1669494563, i: 14 }),
  ns: { db: 'OpenHaus', coll: 'vault' },
  documentKey: { _id: new ObjectId("637a444b8f0dafbfa0f2b058") },
  updateDescription: {
    updatedFields: { secrets: [Array], timestamps: [Object] },
    removedFields: []
  }
}
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: what properties are on the `event` object?  I also dont see a specific `"change"` event in their [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/). Am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @about14sheep I have updated the question, i find documentation terrible here. The property are dependent on the "operationType", e.g. "insert", "replace" or "update". I need to ensure no matter what event type, that i know the origin.

Comment: @about14sheep Sorry, over read your link. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/change-events/update/ The doc for the node.js module is even worse: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.11/ Try and search there for "changeStreams", it drives you insane.

Comment: their examples are pretty lack luster, have you tried getting the [full document](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/#lookup-full-document-for-update-operations) and seeing if there is an identifying property there? I hope someone more knowledgeable on mongodb comes along to help as i cant really do more than spit balling here

Comment: @about14sheep Yup. The problem is i get the full document, but absolutely no indicator from where are the changes origin. No PID, no name, no hash, no id, nothing.

Comment: seems kinda odd to not include where the change came from, especially since, i assume, a user would have to have access in order to make the change. ill upvote and see if that gets you some help m8, sorry

Comment: @about14sheep Thanks anyway :) Currently i try to store the object id of pending documents updates and check when i receive a "change" from the change streams if the id is there, if so, skip everything in the changes streams since the change origin is made from my app. But that feels hacky and is at max a "workaround"

Comment: if no one comes around to help i think you should post that as an answer in case other people have the same issue. best of luck!

Comment: ChangeStream events come straight from the oplog. It's kinda "exposed" replication, and it's only concerned about state change. At this point there is no context of the query, client, or anything but the document itself.

Comment: @AlexBlex Do you see any other chance to achieve this?

Comment: No, nothing out of the box. I would probably add another field "updated_by" with a client alias and a random part, e.g. "myapp_87347". The random part is to ensure the field is always updated and is a part of the change for application updates. Manual updates should have this field unchanged. If discipline is poor, I'd implement some simplistic signature, so the "random" part can be validated for authenticy.  It seems simpler than multi-document transactions, with the only caveat it won't work for "delete" operations.